# OpenGL 3.x - glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) and VAOs

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have a method for initializing my VBO/VAO:

```
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO_VertexShader);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indexData), indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


        // setup VAO
        glBindVertexArray(mVAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO_VertexShader);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBuffer);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And then a separate method for drawing;

```
    glBindVertexArray(mVAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &mIndexBuffer);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Do I need to unbind the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` after my call to `glDrawElements` or is its state 'tied' to the VAO? (So if I unbind the VAO, the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` will also be unbound)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is tied to the VAO state. I quote the OpenGL 3.3 spec: "The resulting vertex array object is a new state vector, comprising all the state values listed in tables 6.4 and 6.5."
Table 6.4 contains `ELEMENT ARRAY BUFFER BINDING`. So no, you do not need to unbind it.

Additionally, you probably want to pass `NULL` as the last parameter to `glDrawElements` in your example, since the address is relative to the bound element array buffer..

Answer (score 0):

Bind your vertex array when you set the vertex attrib pointer.
So basically just don't unbind your vertex array as you only have one.